RAM usage maxing out on timeline anim
I’m fairly new to blender animations. But having looked at optimisation practices like switching to CUDA or OptiX and leveraging the GPU to handle rendering tasks. Which has worked well and I’ve managed to render out a few short animations.
However, I want to create a paint peeling animation as part of a larger project and requires modifiers.
After setting up a mesh and adding the various modifiers to it to create the peel, I try to quick view it in the timeline but my RAM immediately maxes out and Blender crashes. Are explode, cloth etc modifiers know to do this? Or am I missing some setting?
My PC isn’t the fastest but it’s no slouch either.
Blender: 4.2
PC Specs:

CPU: i7-5820k @ 3.6GHz.
RAM: 32gb DDR4 @ 3200 MHz
GPU: RTX 3070ti

